# Android2.x: MediaPlayer error code (1,-19)

Tags: android, media-player

I wrote a simple application which uses the MediaPlayer to play a video. The Video is in the 3gp file format. The Application is working on Android 4.x , but it reports error (1, -19) on Android 2.x . I have only one MediaPlayer Instance and the MediaPlayer reports that error when the MediaPlayer.start() method is called. The video stream is MPEG-4, and the mobile phone can play it in the default player.

Could anyone please tell me the way to solve this problem?

Comment: I add surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS) and solve the problem.And I don't know why  the type isn't automatically set as it is supposed to be.

Comment: This is  Error due to general port processing `const PVMFStatus PVMFErrPortProcessing = (-19)`

Comment: Add the comment as an answer and accept it so the question won't show as unanswered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS) and solve the problem.And I don't know why the type isn't automatically set as it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Android media player is having its own complexities.I personally don't like MediaPlayer Api. Its better to use ExoPlayer. You can customise as per your requirement.
If you are running out of time use some opensource projects like [this](https://github.com/master255/TextureVideoPlayer)